# Security Admins toolkit? What's in yours?

Tags: security

Resource question :- I need to collate a list of security admin tools

For:

- Web
- Network
- Wifi
- Server unix/Linux/windows/macosx
- SQL
- Xss

Please state

-links/version/os used/free v buy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Web

- [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) - A library and utilities to make custom HTTP/FTP requests
- [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) - A utility to quickly download URLs
- [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) - A simple yet powerful utility to open a connection to a remote server or listen on a local port
- [Python's urllib2 module](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) - Great for scripting mass downloads, testing URLs, grabbing data quickly to parse, etc

### Network

- [nmap](http://nmap.org/) - Port scanning, host detection, network mapping, and service detection
- [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - Network protocol analyzer for Win/Linux
- [tcptraceroute](http://michael.toren.net/code/tcptraceroute/) - Traceroute utility using TCP packets instead of ICMP packets to bypass filtering or test firewalls
- [arping](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=arping) and [arpwatch](http://www-nrg.ee.lbl.gov/) - ARP-based utilities to detect and observe ARP activity on the network
- [logcheck](http://logcheck.org/) - Daemon that watches logs and alerts you when unusual events occur
- [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) - Daemon that watches logs and takes action against hosts attempting to guess passwords or attack the network
- [iptables/netfilter](http://www.netfilter.org/) - Linux 2.6 firewall software

### WiFi

- [KisMac](http://kismac.macpirate.ch/) ([Kismet on non-Mac](http://www.kismetwireless.net/)) - WiFi scanner, prober, and cracker
- [iStumbler](http://www.istumbler.net/)/[Netstumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/) - Simple WiFi/bluetooth/Bonjour scanner
- 802.1x w/ RADIUS backend - Prevent unauthorized access to your WiFi/Ethernet network

### SQL

- [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index.html) - Or whatever documentation for your RDBMS of choice

### XSS

- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) - Firefox extension to debug websites
- Safari [Web Inspector and Javascript Console](http://webkit.org/blog/197/web-inspector-redesign/) - Built-in Safari functionality to debug websites

### Everything

- [Google](https://www.google.com/) - Index of all mankind's knowledge
- [Python](http://www.python.org/) - Pseudocode interpreter

Hope some of this helps. This is just what's come to mind so far, but there's tons more out there. Where and when to use each is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Network: tcpdump, iptables, pf, ssh, openssl (and recently gnutls), keytool (java ssl stuff)
SQL: PostgreSQL documentation

Comment: oh and mtr! mtr is great to analy icmp ping stuff

Answer (score 11):

**Web**

For pen testing web sites, try these Firefox extensions:  (All are free.)

- [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)
- [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)
- [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966)

I've also heard good things about [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (freeware, any browser, Windows only).

**General Networking**

- [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - protocol analysis; see what's on your network.  Free, for any OS.
- [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) - generic low-level client and server; the "TCP/IP Swiss army knife."  Free, for any OS.
- [nmap](http://nmap.org/) - scan for open ports and active hosts, and identify OSes and (sometimes) servers.  Free, for any OS.
- [Nessus](http://www.nessus.org/nessus/) - scan for vulnerabilities on your network.  Unix or Linux.

These are the tools I'm most familiar with, but for a much more complete list, see [sectools.org](http://sectools.org/).

**Wireless**

I don't have as much experience with these.

- [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) (free, for any OS)
- [NetStumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/) (for Windows)
- [WiFi Pilot](http://www.cacetech.com/products/wifi_pilot.html?utm_source=Wireshark&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=wifi_pilot&utm_content=wifi_pilot&utm_campaign=Wireshark_Product) (commercial, for Windows, from the principal developers of Wireshark)

Answer (score 5):

Mine:

- [Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) - To script when I don't have the right tool.
- [NetStumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/) - To detect wireless.
- [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) - To sniff traffic.
- [Cain & Abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html) - To crack passwords and exploit LSA Secrets.
- [NMap](http://nmap.org/) - Port Scanner
- [SysInternal PSTools Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) - Ton of useful tools
- [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/) - IE Proxy that allows you to see HTTP Request / Response even with SSL
- [Nessus](http://www.nessus.org/) - General vulnerability scanner
- [SQLPing 3](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/Tools/FreeTools/tabid/65/Default.aspx) - SQL Server scanner
- SQL Server Profiler - to monitor SQL Server commands going to a particular SQL Server
- Command Line - a lot of tools here
- [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) - Unix/Linux tools on Windows.

Comment: Add argus from qosient.com (flow data from network taps) and you cover 90% of the tools I use.

Answer (score 4):

Have you had a look at [BackTrack Linux](http://www.remote-exploit.org/backtrack.html)?

I've written a little framework around it so I can easily drop in my own scripts and packages, that way I just burn a disc each time I need to go remote.

Answer (score 2):

[inSSIDer](http://metageek.net/Products/Inssider) is a nice replacement for NetStumbler that works on x64 Windows. I also like Microsoft's [Network Monitor](http://blogs.technet.com/netmon/) packet analyzer.

Already mentioned was Fiddler which is a very nice http protocol analyzer and of course nmap.

Answer (score 2):

What? No love for physical tools?

- Anti-static Bags
- Small tool kit, belkin or some other
- Hard drive write blocker (IDE)
- A write blocked thumb drive: loaded with AV and other goodies
- A digital camera (especially for taking pictures of BIOS settings)
- Various adapters and gender-benders
- A flashlight/LED keyfob
- A stack of bootdisks
- A stack of blank DVD/CD
- A floppy disk or two (you NEVER know ...)
- A paper notebook: Keeps logs, diagrams, notes, and never needs charging
- Pens and pencils

Another great resource for a list of SA tools, [SAGE Sysadmin Toolbox](http://www.sage.org/field/toolbox.html)